# Changing Render Kits in Browser

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, cross-browser

I'm working on a project to develop a cross-browser testing web app.  Simply put, I'm tired of having to maintain multiple browsers on the same system and IE in VMware solely for the purpose of testing.  Does anyone know if there is any way to change the render kit programmatically?  For example, if I insert a URL, I would be able to load the URL and switch the browser render within a frame of some assortment.  I am experienced with PHP, JS, and RoR if there is a solution using any of those.

Thank you!

John

Answer (score 2):

How do you want to change the browser rendering engine with code executed server side ?

[Lunascape Browser](http://www.lunascape.tv/) permits you to choose between 3 rendering engines with a dropdown menu. It won't be pro grammatically and it needs to run on Windows with Internet Explorer installed, but this will save you some time.

Supported engines :

1. Gecko (Firefox, Mozilla)
2. Trident (Internet explorer)
3. Webkit (Chrome, Safari)

However, if you want to be thorough, you'll still need to test in each browser individually, since there's since each browser as specificity besides the rendering engine.

Comment: +1 - beaten to it. Lunascape is an excellent browser as an element in an overall testing strategy for the three main rendering engines